# In Oracle 11g SQL, is there a order of precedence for update of columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g SQL, I want to know if there is a order of precedence of update of columns in update statement.

I have a update statement like below -

```sql
update table_name set column_1=column_2, column_2=NULL where condition..
```

i.e. we are trying a updating `column_1` with `column_2` values and then update `column_2` with `NULL` (our assumption is that for the update statement, the order of precedence is right to left - i.e. assignment `<column_1>=<column_2>` always happens first and then `<column_2>=NULL` always happens next.

We have tried this and our results back our assumptions. However, I have a feeling that oracle randomly decides the precedence in which update happens. In that case, the results we got might be coincidence. So, wanted to do some more research before we take this live.

```sql
update table_name set column_1=column_2, column_2=NULL where condition
```

Comment: It is not left-to-right as the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2f767166e24bf26a9358f80fda54be7) does not propagate the `NULL` values if you swap the order of the assignments so that `column_2 = NULL` is before `column_1 = column_2` in the statement.

Comment: Oracle knows about the old values of the row and it uses those to find the new values for the columns being updated. You can quite happily do `update table set col1 = col2, col2 = col1` to swap column values: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1cf0822320d66eb376aa7d97da64c1c8.

Comment: The transaction is always atomic, so all updates will happen together as one single transaction or doesn't happen at all. So there is no order between the columns themselves. You could use any order in the set, however they all are updated together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is not in the order of columns, but that Oracle uses the current value of columns, non the updated one, no matter the order you write your code.

For example:

```
SQL> select * from table_name;

   COLUMN1    COLUMN2
---------- ----------
        20          2
        10          1

SQL> update table_name set column1=column2, column2=NULL;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from table_name;

   COLUMN1    COLUMN2
---------- ----------
         2
         1

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select * from table_name;

   COLUMN1    COLUMN2
---------- ----------
        20          2
        10          1

SQL> update table_name set column2=NULL, column1=column2;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from table_name;

   COLUMN1    COLUMN2
---------- ----------
         2
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "order of precedence" that the `UPDATE` statement uses. Instead, Oracle will use the previous value of the column as the result of the expression on the right of the assignment regardless of whether it is being assigned a new value on the left of an assignment.

Consider:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column_1, column_2 ) AS
  SELECT 2 * LEVEL - 1, 2 * LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
```

If you use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET column_2 = NULL, column_1 = column_2
```

or use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = column_2, column_2 = NULL
```

then the result is identical:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table_name
> ```
>
> ```
> COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2
> -------: | -------:
>        2 |     null
>        4 |     null
>        6 |     null
>        8 |     null
>       10 |     null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b00a4bdc4a2a5bf4c84544a075a1a8be)*